# Why do the normals on this Path have varying density?

Tags: normals, path

I added a Path, enabled "Normals" in "Curve Edit Mode Overlays", enabled snap to Increment, and extruded the end of the Path a few times.

[image]

The middle segments are showing more normal arrows than the end segments. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Normal arrows are shown at each place where a point is made to generate the curve.

They are spread unevenly across the whole curve depending on the control points' position, but the start and end points are always on their respective control points. Hence the stretch.

Comment: The points made to generate the curve are evenly spread out at 1 unit distance due to the snap, so that doesn't make sense to me